# Generating specific html tags with c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a website with an image gallery. I want to dynamically add the pictures to the gallery. I have this code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(@"images\gallery\projects"));
string temp = files[0];

for (int i = 1; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    HyperLink hp = new HyperLink();

    hp.ImageUrl = "images/gallery/projects/" + Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
    hp.NavigateUrl = "images/gallery/projects/" + Path.GetFileName(temp);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(hp);
    temp = files[i];
}
```

That iterates the folder with pictures and generates link tag but its not what I need. I am trying to generate this tag:

```
<a href="images/gallery/picture_fullsize.jpg" 
   title="Caption for picture goes here">
    <img src="images/gallery/picture_thumbnail.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Any pointers or solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing method is great which is strongly type, and less error prone than creating a link by yourself.

If you want to add title to a tag, you can use `Attributes.Add` method.

```
var hp = new HyperLink();
hp.ImageUrl = "images/gallery/projects/" + Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
hp.NavigateUrl = "images/gallery/projects/" + Path.GetFileName(temp);
hp.Attributes.Add("title", "Caption for picture goes here");
Panel1.Controls.Add(hp);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you instead solve this using a template control like a repeater. Seems like you're already set up to do that given that you're working with a list that can act as your bound datasource. Dynamically creating html should be avoided when possible.

See more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx). It allows you to create nice clean HTML, and can easily do nested tags like what you want. So your code would look something like this:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)) //Always enclose in 'using' for cleaner code
for (int i = 1; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    //Write the starting 'a' tag
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, "images/gallery/projects/" + Path.GetFileName(temp));
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A); 

    //Write the starting 'img' tag
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, "images/gallery/projects/" + Path.GetFileName(files[i]));
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Img);

    //Close the 'img' tag
    writer.RenderEndTag();

    //Close the 'a' tag
    writer.RenderEndTag();  
}

var generatedHtml = stringWriter.ToString(); //The final HTML
```